# How can I set up twin view on 11.04 with a Matrox G400/G450?

Tags: 11.04, multiple-monitors, twinview, dualhead

I've been trying, quite unsuccessfully, to set up "twin view" on 11.04 with a Matrox G400/G450.

At this point I can't recall what I may have tried.

Currently each monitor is displaying the same video and pressing "Detect Monitors" within System -> Preferences -> Monitors does nothing.

I have scoured the interwebs for instructions, tried several of them to no avail.

Most recently I read through several threads on the Ubuntu forums and it seems many others have the same problem with no resolution.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you include a copy of your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` as this is where the problem usually lies.

Comment: I don't have an xorg.conf.  Perhaps this is something new with 11.04?

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this [website](http://www.schrammel.org/linux-matrox-g450.php?l=en) and the example [xorg.conf](http://www.schrammel.org/download/xorg.conf)

The important part to checkout is `Section "ServerLayout"` at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Perhaps it was not your intent, but I copied and pasted the contents of that xorg.conf and logged out. My monitor "status" led then blinked green rapidly and I had to delete my xorg.conf. Were you suggesting that I copy and paste only portions? I'm a recent Linux convert and so I would most benefit from explicit instructions.

Comment: Yes, you cannot copy it directly as the monitor and device information will be different. I use nvidia and forgot that it creates and stores a new config. Have a look here for steps that might help: [X Config](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#How%20to%20setup%20a%20dual%20monitor)

Comment: None of the posts have helped.  I'm new to Linux and trying to not read through an entire man page nor a verbose page which has tidbits of information depending upon which hardware I'm using.  I strictly want to know how to force my second monitor to be detected. I am now trying to get this to work on 10.04 with the same level of success (which is none). Please, everyone, don't post links to pages. If you don't know the answer or cannot help, please just don't post anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this exact same requirement with the same issue at the moment. Please could someone suggest some ideas. One monitor is a Belinea LCD. The other is a LCD TV with PC input. Here are some more details about the graphics card.

```
dominic@DACSTATION1:~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Matrox Graphics, Inc. MGA G400/G450 [102b:0525] (rev 82)
dominic@DACSTATION1:~$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for dominic:
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: MGA G400/G450
       vendor: Matrox Graphics, Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 82
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm agp agp-2.0 vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=matrox_w1 latency=64 maxlatency=32 mingnt=16
       resources: irq:16 memory:f8000000-f9ffffff memory:fe6fc000-fe6fffff memory:fd800000-fdffffff memory:fe000000-fe01ffff
```

Comment: I could be speaking out of turn, but I think your response should have been a "comment" and not an "answer."